How to select and replace XML using Notepad Replace function with condition
I work with XML which has millions of lines.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ROOT>
<trade idPosition="E56F58837T6827J1173K927479">
  <currency>BTCUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>100000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>Futures</typeOfContract>
  <isActive>1</isActive>
</trade>
<trade idPosition="S28L16487Q9127J7592O836105">
  <currency>ETHUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>1000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>CFD</typeOfContract>
  <isActive>1</isActive>
</trade>
<trade idPosition="B11F00000Z1547A1461H167729">
  <currency>SOLUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>1000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>Futures</typeOfContract>
  <isActive>1</isActive>
</trade>
</ROOT>

I want to substitute all nodes of <trade> with void ("") except nodes that have typeOfContract with CFD value to get that:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ROOT>
<trade idPosition="S28L16487Q9127J7592O836105">
  <currency>ETHUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>1000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>CFD</typeOfContract>
  <isActive>1</isActive>
</trade>
</ROOT>

I tried <trade guid=".*?">(?:(?!</?trade>).)*>CFD<.*?</trade>
but if I put that in the search box and I put "" in the replace box, it doesn't work and deletes too many trading positions...

Do all the <trade> nodes have the structure you have shown with 26-character ID, and three tags each in the <currency>, <lotUSD>, <typeOfContract> order? Would you maybe consider a programmatic solution (e.g. in Python) or it must be done in Notepad?

Your XML is not valid.

The closing tag of lotUSD is still missing....

thanks @luuk, i made the correction. next time try to explain more, not only write "not valid" when u see error thanks

see my answer which also explains how-to validate an XML

When using the plugin XMLTools it is easy to verify the validity of your XML, using "Check XML syntax now" from the plugin menu.
I corrected it, and it looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ROOT>
<trade idPosition="E56F58837T6827J1173K927479">
  <currency>BTCUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>100000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>Futures</typeOfContract>
</trade>
<trade idPosition="S28L16487Q9127J7592O836105">
  <currency>ETHUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>1000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>CFD</typeOfContract>
</trade>
<trade idPosition="B11F00000Z1547A1461H167729">
  <currency>SOLUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>1000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>Futures</typeOfContract>
</trade>
</ROOT>

Another function of this XML Tools is: "XSL Transformation"
When creating a file name "trades.xsl" with the following contents:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="ROOT">
      <xsl:for-each select="//trade[typeOfContract='CFD']">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

You can transform your XML

A new document is created with this content:
<ROOT><trade idPosition="S28L16487Q9127J7592O836105">
  <currency>ETHUSD</currency>
  <lotUSD>1000</lotUSD>
  <typeOfContract>CFD</typeOfContract>
</trade></ROOT>

Info on writing an XSL is pretty hard. (IMHO), that's why I used XmlStarlet which van create XSL stylesheets.
xml sel -C -t -e root -m //trade[typeOfContract='CFD'] -c . trade.xml > trade.xsl


perfect, it work using xsl, it's a good idea to use XPATH requests to do the job. thanks a lot

If all of your nodes share the structure you posted, the following should work (despite not very elegant):
<trade .+>\r\n(.+\r\n){2}\h+<typeOfContract>(?!CFD)[^ ]*</trade>\r\n

I struggled with matching any string but CFD and this answer helped me. Hope this helps you as well!

i tried to use the function, but i see the end </trade>\r\n perturb because in the real file i have lot of nodes. i edited the exemple adding a node <isActive>, the true file have 50 more node but the <isActive> is always the last subnode of every <trade> node. How can i adapt your code to made it work?

If you have more nodes, I suspect that the problem may come from the fact that the string expects the </trade> node to be closed at the line right after <typeOfContract>. I tried to modify the regex, but I am afraid you need someone more experienced than me... As per my comment to the original question, would you be down for a programmatic solution?
